# Why do I need to source ~/.bashrc manually everytime when I connecting via SSH?

Tags: bash, ssh, bashrc

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 ,and use ssh to connect to my lab's server. But since a week ago, every time I open a terminal through ssh, I can't use `conda activate *`, [it says don't have the command "conda".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC0gy.png) 
Then I tried many ways, and found I need to write

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

then I could use conda and everything
[works well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2AXJ.png)
Why can't my terminal run .bashrc automatically when I restart a terminal?
Do anyone know why it happens and how to solve it permanently?

I checked the `.bashrc` file and it seems it works well and I do have a `.bash_profile` file, but it is empty, I don't know if it has something to do with my situation. And I don't have a `.bash_login` file.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` is sourced from one of these files: `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`. Check if any of these files are present, and if `~/.bashrc` is sourced correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile`: (for `~/.bash_profile` you can ommit the outer "if" statement checking that you're running Bash)

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Alternately, if you already have a `~/.profile` with the proper contents, you can delete `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.profile` will be used instead.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! And I think it is because I have both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile`, but my `~/.bash_profile` is empty , when I delete the empty file , everything works well. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why. If `~/.bash_profile` exists, it overrides the normal `~/.profile` file, and if it's empty, then it's better to just remove it.